# Rust function requires return keyword. Why?

Tags: rust

I've been playing with Rust a bit, and I'm experimenting with eliminating `return` statements that aren't necessary. In one case, I feel as though a `return` statement shouldn't be required here, but I'm getting complaints that "the body has no tail". It seems like it should with the following code:

```rust
use sqlite;
use sqlite::Connection

fn main() {
    let connection = connect();

    query(connection);
}

// The offending function
fn connect() -> Connection {
    // Simple example, shouldn't use unwrap
    sqlite::open(":memory:").unwrap();
}
```

I can add a `return` statement to the offending function like the following:

```rust
fn connect() -> Connection {
    return sqlite::open(":memory:").unwrap();
}
```

But I'm curious why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fn connect() -> Connection {
    sqlite::open(":memory:").unwrap()
}
```

Removing the semi-colon, changes the line from a [statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html) to an [expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html), which has a return value, which Rust can then infer as a return value for the function.

This is covered at the very end [Chapter 3 of the Rust language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html) book as a specific example.